# How to iterate through a map of objects using .next()?

Tags: java, object, dictionary, iterator

I've implemented `Iterable` in my Location class that stores a map of objects to allow iteration through each object within the map.

But when I tested this code, only the first location is loaded, ie "Tiberius"
when I give the input a, `move` command.

Does anyone why the next location in the map isn't being loaded in this implementation?

This is the map that locations are added to and the iterator method:

```
private Map<Location, Integer> children = new HashMap<Location, Integer>();



        @Override
        public Iterator<Location> iterator() {
             return children.keySet().iterator();
        }
```

The main class where .next() is called on the start location:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        //Boolean to signify game state 
        boolean gameNotOver = true;

        Location nextLocation = new Location();
        Location startNode = new Location();

        Iterator<Location> nodeIterator = startNode.iterator();


        GameMap playerMap = new GameMap();
        playerMap.getStartNode();

        //get the first location in the map
        startNode = playerMap.getStartNode();

        //main game loop
        while (gameNotOver) {

            Main mainObj = new Main();

            //Take in user commands here
            //and parse commands
            String input = Input.getInput();
            if (input.equals("description")) {
                System.out.println("Description: " );
            } else if (input.equals("move")) {
                System.out.println("Moving.. " );
                //call the next location in the map
                startNode.next();
                System.out.println(startNode.toString());
            //Invalid input check
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid command, try again!");
            }

        }

        //Game over 
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're setting `nodeIterator()` but not using it, and you're calling `next()` on `Location` which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Where's the part where you insert items into `playerMap`? Please provide code that can be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
startNode.next();
System.out.println(startNode.toString());
```

But you never change startNode. No wonder why always the same location is printed. Change this code to

```
startNode = startNode.next();
System.out.println(startNode.toString());
```

and it should work.